# How to use grep to extract multiple groups

Tags: regex, grep, pcre

Say I have this file `data.txt`:

```
a=0,b=3,c=5
a=2,b=0,c=4
a=3,b=6,c=7
```

I want to use `grep` to extract 2 columns corresponding to the values of `a` and `c`:

```
0 5
2 4
3 7
```

I know how to extract each column separately:

```
grep -oP 'a=\K([0-9]+)' data.txt
0
2
3
```

And:

```
grep -oP 'c=\K([0-9]+)' data.txt
5
4
7
```

But I can't figure how to extract the two groups. I tried the following, which didn't work:

```
grep -oP 'a=\K([0-9]+),.+c=\K([0-9]+)' data.txt
5
4
7
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am also curious about `grep` being able to do so. `\K` "removes" the previous content that is stored, so you cannot use it twice in the same expression: it will just show the last group. Hence, it should be done differently.

In the meanwhile, I would use `sed`:

```
sed -r 's/^a=([0-9]+).*c=([0-9]+)$/\1 \2/' file
```

it catches the digits after `a=` and `c=`, whenever this happens on lines starting with `a=` and not containing anything else after `c=digits`.

For your input, it returns:

```
0 5
2 4
3 7
```

Comment: Great solution.

Answer (score 9):

You could try the below grep command. But note that , grep would display each match in separate new line. So you won't get the format like you mentioned in the question.

```
$ grep -oP 'a=\K([0-9]+)|c=\K([0-9]+)' file
0
5
2
4
3
7
```

To get the mentioned format , you need to pass the output of `grep`  to `paste` or any other commands .

```
$ grep -oP 'a=\K([0-9]+)|c=\K([0-9]+)' file | paste -d' ' - -
0 5
2 4
3 7
```

Answer (score 1):

use this :

```
awk -F[=,] '{print $2" "$6}' data.txt
```

I am using the separators as `=` and `,`, then spliting  on them